# Two external IPs on Google Cloud VM

Tags: routing, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, external-ip

I would like to ask if it's possible to have two external IPs on one VM in Google cloud. My intention is to have small weather VM which will collect data send to internet on one IP which will also server as management interface (nic0 - ssh + weather collect port) and another IP which will be used for Web services to present data (nic1 - http+https). I have created two networks with necessary firewall rules and VM with two interfaces and two external IPs but I am able to reach only external IP on nic0. Ping/telnet fails to reach IP address on nic1. Is there something I missed (routing for example) or it's allowed to use just one external IP per machine?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found solution here. It was necessary to modify routing tables.

https://freelinuxtutorials.com/configuring-multiple-interfaces-multiple-default-routes-linux/

Comment: it is possible ut not necessarily?